# If $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ and $a \in \Bbb{R}$ prove $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is absolutely continuous and of bounded variation.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I am given some $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ and am asked to prove $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is of bounded variation and absolutely continuous. I have shown bounded variation. Was a bit stuck on showing absolute continuity.

**Attempt:**

For some partition $x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n$, note that

\begin{align*}
        \bigg\vert F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1}) \bigg\vert&=\bigg\vert \int_a^{x_i} f(t) dt - \int_a^{x_{i-1}} f(t) dt \bigg\vert && \text{by definition}\\
        &= \bigg \vert \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f(t) dt \bigg \vert && \text{as $x_{i-1}<x_i$}\\
        &\leq \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \vert f \vert dt && \text{Triangle inequality}\\
        &< \infty && \text{as $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$}
    \end{align*}
Thus the supremum is finite over all partitions and $f$ is of bounded variation. For absolute continuity, I need to show for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\vert x - y \vert < \delta$, then $\vert F(x) - F(y) \vert < \epsilon$. Also, this definition of absolute continuity isnt really the version I am after, and am I asked to show $F$ is absolutely continuous on all of $\Bbb{R}$? Or am I using that if $F$ is of BV, then we can express it as the difference of two increasing functions? Call them $F_1,F_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutely continuous function is, for any $\epsilon>0$,there is $\delta>0$, such that any finite disjoint interval $(x_i,y_i)$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{n}（y_i-x_i)<\delta$, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(y_i)-f(x_i)| < \epsilon.$$
Back to your question, since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that for any $e \subset \mathbb{R}$ with Leberger measure less than $\delta$, there holds $ \int_{e}|f|dx < \epsilon $.
Now, for any finite number of disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n),$$
when the sum of their lengths is less than $\delta$, we have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}|F(y_i)-F(x_i)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{x_i}^{y_i} |f|dx <\epsilon.$$